# Sudden malfunction/failure of SSD SATA drive - status: { DRDY }, SRST failed (errno=-16)

Tags: ssd, data-recovery, hardware-failure

The SSD stopped working after connecting HDD to the same controller using another cable. Using Linux USB live-cd I see this in dmesg:

```
20.606155] EXT4-fs (sda2): mounting ext3 file system using the ext4 subsystem
[   20.607883] EXT4-fs (sda2): INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem
[   20.607988] EXT4-fs (sda2): write access will be enabled during recovery
[   80.888083] ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen
[   80.888171] ata1.00: failed command: FLUSH CACHE EXT
[   80.888254] ata1.00: cmd ea/00:00:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/a0 tag 0
                        res 40/00:01:00:00:00/00:00:00:00:00/00 Emask 0x4 (timeout)
[   80.888408] ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
[   80.888487] ata1.00: hard resetting link
[   81.203935] ata1.01: hard resetting link
[   82.244056] ata1.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
[   87.444057] ata1.00: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[   90.924057] ata1.00: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[   90.924137] ata1.00: hard resetting link
[   91.239949] ata1.01: hard resetting link
[   92.280056] ata1.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
[   97.480057] ata1.00: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  100.959977] ata1.00: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[  100.960058] ata1.00: hard resetting link
[  101.274332] ata1.01: hard resetting link
[  102.311977] ata1.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
[  107.512056] ata1.00: link is slow to respond, please be patient (ready=0)
[  136.012054] ata1.00: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[  136.012132] ata1.00: limiting SATA link speed to 1.5 Gbps
[  136.012216] ata1.00: hard resetting link
[  136.327925] ata1.01: hard resetting link
[  137.368056] ata1.01: failed to resume link (SControl 0)
[  141.068041] ata1.00: SRST failed (errno=-16)
[  141.079858] ata1.00: reset failed, giving up
[  141.079929] ata1.00: disabled
[  141.080011] ata1: EH complete
[  141.080103] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  141.080219] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Synchronize Cache(10) 35 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
[  141.080333] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[  141.080502] JBD2: recovery failed
[  141.080594] EXT4-fs (sda2): error loading journal
[  141.087107] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  141.087230] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 1f 07 b8 00 00 00 20 00
[  141.087337] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 520599552
[  141.087520] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  141.087638] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 1f 07 b8 00 00 00 08 00
[  141.087745] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 520599552
[  141.087824] Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 0, async page read
[  141.094200] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  141.094323] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 12 c8 00 00 00 20 00
[  141.094432] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 18008064
[  141.094612] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  141.094744] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 12 c8 00 00 00 02 00
[  141.094851] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 18008064
[  141.094929] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 0, async page read
[  141.095053] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  141.095166] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 12 c8 02 00 00 02 00
[  141.095273] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 18008066
[  141.095349] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 1, async page read
[  141.095458] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  141.095571] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 12 c8 04 00 00 02 00
[  141.095677] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 18008068
[  141.095754] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 2, async page read
[  141.095860] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  141.095983] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 01 12 c8 06 00 00 02 00
[  141.096091] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 18008070
[  141.096168] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 3, async page read
[  141.302353] ISO 9660 Extensions: Microsoft Joliet Level 3
[  141.308138] ISO 9660 Extensions: RRIP_1991A
[  143.664195] random: crng init done
[  143.664278] random: 7 urandom warning(s) missed due to ratelimiting
[  143.757956] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  143.758080] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 e4 36 00 00 00 08 00
[  143.758187] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 937702912
[  143.758412] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  143.758544] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 e4 36 00 00 00 08 00
[  143.758650] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 937702912
[  143.758728] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 117212864, async page read
[  143.760227] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 0, async page read
[  143.762692] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 117212864, async page read
[  143.764075] Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 0, async page read
[  143.766392] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 117212864, async page read
[  151.652888] ip_tables: (C) 2000-2006 Netfilter Core Team
[  151.667361] systemd[1]: systemd 237 running in system mode. (+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid)
[  151.684246] systemd[1]: Detected architecture x86-64.
[  151.699817] systemd[1]: Set hostname to <mint>.
[  151.941123] systemd[1]: Reached target Remote File Systems.
[  151.941788] systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
[  151.942225] systemd[1]: Reached target User and Group Name Lookups.
[  151.942969] systemd[1]: Set up automount Arbitrary Executable File Formats File System Automount Point.
[  151.943421] systemd[1]: Reached target Swap.
[  151.944365] systemd[1]: Created slice User and Session Slice.
[  151.945030] systemd[1]: Created slice System Slice.
[  152.194071] lp: driver loaded but no devices found
[  152.240035] ppdev: user-space parallel port driver
[  152.248140] systemd-journald[831]: Received request to flush runtime journal from PID 1
[  152.338874] scsi_io_completion: 24 callbacks suppressed
[  152.338887] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  152.338897] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[  152.338900] print_req_error: 24 callbacks suppressed
[  152.338903] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[  152.339316] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  152.339324] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 e4 36 00 00 00 08 00
[  152.339328] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 937702912
[  152.339519] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  152.339526] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 37 e4 36 a0 00 00 08 00
[  152.339530] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 937703072
[  152.339704] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  152.339711] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[  152.339714] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[  152.339865] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  152.339872] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 08 00 00 08 00
[  152.339875] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 8
[  152.340978] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  152.340986] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[  152.340990] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[  152.341645] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  152.341652] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 1f 07 af 80 00 00 08 00
[  152.341656] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 520597376
[  152.341854] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  152.341861] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 1f 07 af f0 00 00 08 00
[  152.341864] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 520597488
[  152.342044] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  152.342051] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 07 52 c8 00 00 00 08 00
[  152.342054] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 122865664
[  152.342228] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  152.342235] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 07 52 c8 08 00 00 08 00
[  152.342239] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 122865672

.... skipped ....

154.024673] buffer_io_error: 11 callbacks suppressed
[  154.024678] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 117212864, async page read
...
[  154.558029] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 52428608, async page read
[  154.558178] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 52428609, async page read
[  154.558294] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 52428610, async page read
[  154.558419] Buffer I/O error on dev sda4, logical block 52428611, async page read
[  154.562397] Buffer I/O error on dev sda2, logical block 49716464, async page read
[  154.564862] Buffer I/O error on dev sda3, logical block 52137920, async page read

...

339.695928] perf: interrupt took too long (2501 > 2500), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 79750
[  419.711202] perf: interrupt took too long (3150 > 3126), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 63500
[  513.633303] perf: interrupt took too long (3944 > 3937), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 50500
[  671.315820] perf: interrupt took too long (4944 > 4930), lowering kernel.perf_event_max_sample_rate to 40250
[  776.515277] scsi_io_completion: 21 callbacks suppressed
[  776.515290] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  776.515301] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[  776.515304] print_req_error: 21 callbacks suppressed
[  776.515307] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[  776.515388] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  776.515395] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[  776.515398] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[  776.515406] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
[  776.515467] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  776.515473] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[  776.515477] print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
[  776.515482] Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
[  776.516889] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(16) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  776.516896] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[  776.516966] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Read Capacity(10) failed: Result: hostbyte=DID_BAD_TARGET driverbyte=DRIVER_OK
[  776.516970] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Sense not available.
[  776.517044] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] 0 512-byte logical blocks: (0 B/0 B)
[  776.517155] sda: detected capacity change from 480103981056 to 0
```

The Drive detectable in BIOS though and initially after reboot I can see it's partition table using lsblk:

```
mint@mint:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0    7:0    0   1.8G  1 loop /rofs
sda      8:0    0 447.1G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0 189.7G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0 198.9G  0 part 
└─sda4   8:4    0    50G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   1   3.8G  0 disk /cdrom
├─sdb1   8:17   1   1.9G  0 part 
└─sdb2   8:18   1   2.3M  0 part
```

Smartmontools couldn't detect it though as functioning device:

```
mint@mint:~$ sudo smartctl /dev/sda
...
Short INQUIRY response, skip product id
A mandatory SMART command failed: exiting. To continue, add one or more '-T permissive' options.
```

But after trying to run fdisk on it, it disappears and fdisk reports:

`fdisk: cannot open /dev/sda: Input/output error`

hdparm -I before using fdisk reports:

```
mint@mint:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 HDIO_DRIVE_CMD(identify) failed: Input/output error
mint@mint:~$ sudo hdparm -I /dev/sdb

/dev/sdb:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

ATA device, with non-removable media
Standards:
    Likely used: 1
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   0   0
    heads       0   0
    sectors/track   0   0
    --
    Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes 
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
    IORDY not likely
    Cannot perform double-word IO
    R/W multiple sector transfer: not supported
    DMA: not supported
    PIO: pio0
```

Any suggestion to make further steps to investigate the issue, if any are possible at all, as well as any explanation about what I'm dealing here with are welcomed and will be appreciated. Please do not write here "throw it in the bin" if you know nothing about what exactly is going on here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Swap back to the original cable would be the first step. Dodgy cables cause all sorts of random errors, including *actually* destroying the drive permanently. I lost one last year due to that.

Comment: It happened on it's original cable which wasn't touched for 2 years. I just added another HDD to another port of the same SATA controller. The ouput quoted above was generated using another machine (laptop) booted from a first USB stick (LinuxMint live-cd) I just happened to have around. Seems like I've lost mine too because of some seemingly very odd glitch.

Comment: Also check the power cables. May be this is the effect of a PSU or power cable problem?

Comment: Could it be a power issue? If so, does the SSD work OK if you disconnect the HDD?

Comment: @TommyPeanuts, no it doesn't. if it worked I wouldn't bother to post a request for help here, obviously, mate.